# Populating Tables with Time values and

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to populate a table that shows start times for fitness classes. An example of a record would be:

```
 Insert into FITNESS_CLASS (StartDate, DaysHeld, TimePeriod, CourseID, RoomNo) 
      values (07-Feb-2014', 'M' 'W', 06:00-7:05, '1309','709');
```

I keep getting errors with the days and the time. It tells me the colon in between the hours and minutes is incorrect, but when I remove it, I am restricted again because it reads it as an "int" data type. How do I populate the times into my tables as well as the days the classes are offered.

Comment: The missing quotes for your date and time?

Answer (score 0):

It needs quotes.

```
Insert into FITNESS_CLASS (StartDate, DaysHeld, TimePeriod, CourseID, RoomNo) 
values ('07-Feb-2014', 'M W', '06:00-7:05', '1309','709');
```

I would also suggest storing the times separately so you can treat them as actual datetime values and/or query against them in a more useful way.